# Probability of choosing subsets $A$, $B$ such that $A\cap \!\,B=\varnothing \!\,$ and $A\cup \!\,B=X$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm given a set

$X={\{\ \!\,1,2,3,...,n\!\ \}} $,

and I have to calculate the probability that, for two randomly chosen, different, non-empty sets

$A, B$: $A,B\subseteq \!\,X$,

we have $A\cap \!\,B=\varnothing \!$ and $A\cup \!\,B=X$.

I'm aware that the number of *possible* cases is $(2^n-1)(2^n-2)$, but I don't know how to count the cases which satisfy the above, which is the gist of the question.

Also, what would be the probability for the same problem, just without the $A\cup \!\,B=X$ part?

**Edit:**

This was my professor's solution for the first problem (with both conditions):

$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n \choose k} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} {n-k\choose i}}{(2^n-1)(2^n-2)}$

Does this make any sense to anyone?

Comment: Is the distribution on the power set uniform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *probability* depends on how likely each subset is.  With the assumption that each subset is equally likely, counting the subsets suffices.

If we assume that $A$ and $B$ are chosen in such a way that they must be distinct (though not necessarily mutually exclusive), then your value for the number of possible cases is correct.  Of those, how many satisfy the conditions?  (I knew what you meant.)

$A$ can be chosen to be any set other than the empty set and the entire set $X$.  Then $B$ has only one choice: $X-A$.  Thus, the number of selections that satisfy the conditions is $2^n-2$, and the probability is $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$.

Comment: That is SO simple, I feel stupid now! I was confused, since my teaching assistent at college came to this solution (which I will write as an edit to my question). Could her solution be right for this other case, without the union condition?

Comment: You mean, what is the probability that two non-identical, non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$ have an empty intersection?  That certainly isn't $1/(2^n-1)$; it's clearly more likely.

Comment: I meant the solution in the edit. Sorry, I wasn't clear.

Comment: So if the professor's solution is correct, that nasty double sum in the numerator evaluates to $2^n-2$.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the solution to the second part (without the complete cover part)?  Structurally, it seems more suited to that part, and I think the value is correct, too.

Comment: The numerator can be simplified, though, to just a single summation: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \left(2^{n-k}-1\right)$.

Comment: @BrianTung That's what I thought also. It would make more sense, even though I still don't see how she got to that :)

Comment: @Brian: Yes, you are right. For $n=3$, the numerator equals $12$, which gives the answer to the second part. The expression is not so opaque $-$ $k$ is the size of $A$, and $i$ is the size of $B$.

Comment: $A$ may be any subset of size $k$, for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.  That's the first summation.  Given $A$, $B$ may be any subset of size $i$, for $1 \leq i \leq n-k$, since $n-k$ is the cardinality of $X-A$.  That's the second summation.  The simplification comes from recognizing that the $(n-k)$th row of Pascal's triangle sums to $2^{n-k}$, and taking out that zeroth entry, which equals $1$.  (Assuming that the $1$ atop Pascal's triangle is the zeroth row.)

Comment: @BrianTung I finally understand, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Given a set $A$, there is only one subset $B \subset X$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = X$, namely the complement $A^c := X - A$ of $A$.

Comment: Though you need to take account of the possibility that $A=X$

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's a separate insight from the intended content of the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the given conditions you can say that:
B=X-A.
Thus if you select A, you also indirectly select B.
Thus you just need to choose A which can be done in (2^n)-2.